# Ruby Nokogiri не парсит/сохраняет данные из страницы

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

Разбираюсь с Nokogiri. По идее, данный код должен переходить на страницу, парсить оттуда информацию и помещать ее в pets_array, который потом передается в csv-файл. но код не срабатывает - файл пустой. Помогите понять, в чем проблема.

```
require 'Nokogiri'
require 'HTTParty'

page = HTTParty.get('https://newyork.craigslist.org/search/pet?s=0')

parse_page = Nokogiri::HTML(page)

pets_array = []

parse_page.css('.content').css('row').css('.hdrlnk').map do |a|
    post_name = a.text
    pets_array << post_name
end

file = CSV.open('pets.csv', 'w') do |csv|
    csv << pets_array
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка в строке

```
parse_page.css('.content').css('row').css('.hdrlnk').map do |a|
```

Вы ищите тэг `<row...>`, вместо класса `class="rows"`, исправьте следующим образом

```
parse_page.css('.content').css('.rows').css('.hdrlnk').map do |a|
```